# Javascript REGEX for Subdomain (Optional)

Tags: regex

I am looking for a REGEX (JS) that I can use to match all subdomains for a domain as well as the TLD domain in email addresses.

Here is an example:

**I would like to be able to match any the following:**

- joe@canada.ca
- joe@it.canada.ca
- joe.smith@business.canada.ca

**But not match**

- joe@visitcanada.ca

By default we use something like:

```
/(.*)@(.*)canada\.ca/gm
```

But this matches all of the above.  Would ideally like a single REGEX that will accomplish all of this.

Comment: Why are you matching an `@`? The current pattern does not match any of the above

Comment: They are email addresses we are checking against.  Left that off. sorry

Comment: Like this? `^[^\s@]+@(?:[^\s.]+\.)*canada\.ca$` https://regex101.com/r/etLosM/1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use

```
^[^\s@]+@(?:[^\s@.]+\.)*canada\.ca$
```

- `^` Start of string
- `[^\s@]+` Match 1+ chars other than a whitespace char or @
- `@` Match literally
- `(?:[^\s@.]+\.)*` Match optional repetitions of 1+ chars other than a whitespace char, `@` or dot, and then match the `.`
- `canada\.ca` Match canada.ca (Note to escape the dot to match it literally
- `$` End of string

[Regex 101 demo](https://regex101.com/r/GqYamJ/1).

```js
const regex = /^[^\s@]+@(?:[^\s@.]+\.)*canada\.ca$/;
[
  "joe@canada.ca",
  "joe@it.canada.ca",
  "joe.smith@business.canada.ca",
  "joe@visitcanada.ca",
].forEach(s => console.log(`${s} --> ${regex.test(s)}`));
```

Comment: That works.  Now I need to use it to learn from.  Thank you

Comment: @VisualSP-DEV This is a pretty good site for [visualizing regexes](https://regexper.com/#%5E%5B%5E%5Cs%40%5D%2B%40%28%3F%3A%5B%5E%5Cs%40.%5D%2B%5C.%29*canada%5C.ca%24)

Comment: Thanks, @Gary - I will look at that

Answer (score 0):

An easier way is to simply anchor `canada` to a word boundary using `\b`, that way you can use your regex pretty much word for word:

```js
.*@.*\bcanada\.ca
```

Comment: That would allow things like "joe@visit-canada.ca"

Comment: @Blindy - thanks, I will look at you solution as well.

Comment: Well we're talking about regex here and parsing email addresses. No matter how good you are and how many pages of regex you write, it still won't be RFC-conforming. This is simple and it matches every one of the OP's test cases :)

Comment: I think this falls outside the spirit of the question by matching other valid/simple domains.  But I agree with your overall point.